# Combining data frames into specific lists in R

Tags: r, dataframe, combinations

I have two data.frames:

```
data.frame.i <- data.frame(mean.sw.i,mean.rep.i,sd.sw.i,sd.rep.i,n.sw.i,n.rep.i)
data.frame.c <- data.frame(mean.sw.c,mean.rep.c,sd.sw.c,sd.rep.c,n.sw.c,n.rep.c)
```

And what I'm trying to do is combined them, so that all the means, sd, and n-values are in the same respective columns (means, sd, n), but if it came from data.frame.i it will label with an "i" in an additional column (called "group" just say) and same for data that came from data.frame.c. Basically I'm asking how do we combine data.frames?!

Any help will be greatly appreciated! This community is the best :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not exactly clear what you want as a result, so please provide a reproducible example and your desired result.

You can put the data frames into a list, iterate through them with `lapply` to make the names consistent, and use `rbind` to bring them together.

Here's a little example of that:

```
(df1 <- data.frame(x.i = 1, y.i = 2))
#   x.i y.i
# 1   1   2
(df2 <- data.frame(x.c = 3, y.c = 4))
#   x.c y.c
# 1   3   4
do.call(rbind, lapply(list(df1, df2), function(x) {
    setNames(x, sub("[.](.*)", "", names(x)))
}))
#   x y
# 1 1 2
# 2 3 4
```

Comment: Fantastic, you sir are a boss.